# Почему запускается 6 виртуальных консолей tty в linux?

Tags: linux, консоль

Странный немного вопрос, знаю что можно переопределить это число, но для чего запускается 6 tty или больше, разве не достаточно одного терминала для работы?

Comment: Видимо,  недостаточно!

Comment: А когда по ssh подключаемся, мы используем один из этих терминалов?

Comment: нет, не используем

Comment: От дистрибутива зависит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**: так просто было удобно и так сложилось исторически

Длинный ответ.
Потому что так вначале сконфигурировали и никто  не трогает это. Когда то давно, когда иксов не было или их запустить было немного накладно, а screen/tmux ещё не изобрели, реально можно было запустить "одну программу на экране". А хочется и компиляцию запустить и шуточки свежие почитать и почту проверить, и что бы ещё начальник ничего не понял. А тут ещё коллега пришел, говорит "мне только в каталог глянуть в файл результатов". И когда есть несколько виртуальных консолей, это сделать очень и очень легко.

Один мой знакомый больше 20 лет назад разрабатывал UI полноэкранное приложение, и в одном экране держал эмакс, а в tty7 (где обычно живет X), запускал тестирование. Говорит, было супер удобно. Сейчас конечно бы можно уже было использовать XNest/Xypher.

похожий ответ на сайте убунту https://askubuntu.com/questions/377213/why-so-many-virtual-consoles

Comment: требую **tl;dr**

Comment: От дистрибутива зависит.